# Front page has a shortened form of my articles

Tags: blocks

In my Main Page Content block, I'm getting a list of recent articles with a "Read more" link.

What do I do if I want the whole article to appear on the front page?

[image: truncated articles on my front page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a couple of assumptions that you are using Drupal 8, and that the front page is using the default Frontpage view. In this case, you can edit the view by logging in as an administrator and editing the view page under Structure - Views - Frontpage (or go to the path admin/structure/views/view/frontpage/edit/page_1). In the first column of this page there is a section called FORMAT. Under the FORMAT section there is a Format and Show row. My guess is Show is set to show content using the teaser view mode. You can change this to show the full content by clicking on "Teaser" and selecting "Full content". After you save the view then you should see the full content of the article on the front page.